# In Ruby, how do I skip a loop in a .each loop, similar to 'continue'

Tags: ruby, loops, syntax, iteration

In Ruby, how do I skip a loop in a `.each` loop, similar to `continue` in other languages?

Answer (score 684, accepted):

Use `next`:

```
(1..10).each do |a|
  next if a.even?
  puts a
end
```

prints:

```
1
3   
5
7
9
```

For additional coolness check out also `redo` and `retry`.

Works also for friends like `times`, `upto`, `downto`, `each_with_index`, `select`, `map` and other iterators (and more generally blocks).

For more info see http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UL.

Comment: Yes, though break isn't that cool (and is a lot more useful ;).

Comment: break is a wrong answer in this case. It stop the .each not just keep 1 loop. ;)

Answer (score 60):

`next` - it's like `return`, but for blocks! (So you can use this in any `proc`/`lambda` too.)

That means you can also say `next n` to "return" `n` from the block.  For instance:

```
puts [1, 2, 3].map do |e|
  next 42 if e == 2
  e
end.inject(&:+)
```

This will yield `46`.

Note that `return` *always* returns from the closest `def`, and never a block; if there's no surrounding `def`, `return`ing is an error.

Using `return` from within a block intentionally can be confusing.  For instance:

```
def my_fun
  [1, 2, 3].map do |e|
    return "Hello." if e == 2
    e
  end
end
```

`my_fun` will result in `"Hello."`, not `[1, "Hello.", 2]`, because the `return` keyword pertains to the outer `def`, not the inner block.

Comment: It would be more interesting to give an example of the `next n`, instead of the `return foo`.

Comment: @ANeves thanks for feedback; have revised to better contrast `next`/`return`.